# Is there a javascript library to fix IE rendering bugs?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, browser-bugs

Our website looks great in all browsers except IE 6-8. We're not even using many CSS3 features. These are just plain old IE rendering bugs (like margins and padding). Before trying to apply a bunch of IE specific fixes, I was wondering if anyone knows of a javascript library that I could apply to fix a bunch of these typical bugs?

**Update:** Like I mentioned, we're not necessarily using any "modern" CSS3 features nor HTML5, so these are just typical IE 8 bugs where IE renders things differently than all the other browsers.

Comment: Yeah its called chrome/firefox... in seriousness check out the html5 boilerplate.

Comment: "IE rendering bug" is incredibly vague. Particularly because you say that IE8 (which is generally reasonable) also has these problems, the "bugs" could instead be problems of your own creation.

Comment: Just because IE renders things differently, doesn't mean it's a bug.

Answer (score 4):

Go for excellent [**normalize.css reset**](http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/) that takes care of most of it (also used by [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/))

> Normalize.css is a customisable CSS file that makes browsers render
>   all elements more consistently and in line with modern standards. We
>   researched the differences between default browser styles in order to
>   precisely target only the styles that need normalizing.

As for getting support of CSS3 for browsers that don't support it, check out [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need JavaScript; just use a CSS reset file: http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/cssreset/

That will work across most browsers to not only fix IE issues, but also make your site render more uniformly over different browsers.

Answer (score 1):

You might wanna take a look at this one: https://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/
or this: https://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/